# Display a grid using divs

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to practice some CSS/HTML, and I am listing what should be done in a table using divs.

The issue I am having is that when I am setting the margin's, the text isn't lining up into columns properly because some text is longer than others, so it results in a jagged table.

e.g.

```
123 hello coool
123 asdfasdfsadf  cool
123 hello coool
123 asdfasdfasdf  kkk
```

So the spacing between each section is correct i.e. 20px, but since the text varies in length it doesn't look aligned.

what's the issue here? is there a solution to this 
(I know a table would make it easier, but I want to learn the div way)

Comment: The div way is to use a table.

Tabular data goes in tables, there's no reason to use divs for what they're not meant.

Comment: @Tordek Read my mind -- the "problem" with tables is that they were being abused for layouts (although considering only the CSS3 Template Layout Module has actually been designed to properly address layouts...). However, if it's tabular data, it's tabular data. That is as much semantic as it is visual and is likely a suitable scenario for using a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you getting your divs to line up next to each other -- that is, simulate rows? If you are using floats, e.g. `float: left`, then the effect you're experiencing is commonly known as shrink-wrapping. In a shrink-wrapped `div`, the div's width will automatically correspond to the length of the content.

The only pure html/css way around this is explicitly set the `width` property of your `div`. You'd need to set each of the `divs` in a column to the same explicit width. In order for this to be effective, you need to have some idea of the length of your content, and set `width` at least as wide.

If you want each `div` in a column to dynamically inherit a width from whichever `div` ends up having the longest content, you'd have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not assigning them fixed widths, causing them to just be sized automatically. Tables will automatically make each cell in a column the same width, but it cannot be done using s, you need to set a fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

You could make each column its own div. EG:

```
<div class="col1">
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="col1">
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>asdfasdfasdf</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>asdfasdfasdf</p>
</div>
<div class="col1">
    <p>cooool</p>
    <p>cooool</p>
    <p>cooool</p>
    <p>cooool</p>
</div>
```

and do

```
.col1 {
    float: left;
}
```

but it will only result in pain and suffering.

I don't know why you want to do it this way; perhaps you heard "tables are wrong", but that is incomplete. The whole phrase is "tables are wrong *for layout*".

Use tables for tabular data, like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a table vs divs, it should be a table vs. semantic markup. If you just replace all the table elements with divs you're missing the entire point of the whole thing.

Also in your example you would use a table.